# Can /etc/hosts values be used while still (rapidly) falling back to their DNS values?

Tags: linux, networking, dns, hosts, hosts-file

I have a server hosted on my home network. Normally, I would access this from its DNS value (e.g. `example.com`.) However, my ISP has an awkward setup wherein I cannot access my home network's external IP from within the network, so when I am at home I am forced to change which value I use. This is difficult for some things.

Can I set an `/etc/hosts` value pointing `example.com` to my local IP, but make it fall back immediately if it has even the slightest bit of trouble reaching the device, so that my work from elsewhere isn't slowed down?

Comment: Is this on a mobile device (e.g., a laptop) which is sometimes on your home network and sometimes on a public network?

Comment: Regarding "cannot access my home network's external IP from within the network" – unfortunately that's the _normal_ setup, as implementing this functionality (NAT hairpinning) is rather troublesome. But many routers do support this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way resolving (DNS resolution) works is that the application asks the resolver for an IP address corresponding to a hostname. The resolver tries several methods (configurable), among them `/etc/hosts`, and returns the addresses from the first successful source to the application.

The resolver usually cannot be asked to merge information from all sources; it uses the first result found, in this case it always returns information from /etc/hosts only.

Also, the resolver has no control over the actual connection establishment. The application itself decides which address to use when creating a connection, and how long to wait before giving up before trying the next one (if at all).

So no, you can't have an automatic fallback "if the application has even the slightest bit of trouble reaching the device", unless you specifically program the application to behave this way.

However, you can detect if you're in your home network, and use different configurations depending on whether you are or not.

This will either require a bit of scripting on your laptop, or a DNS (proxy) server in your home network that you control.